# docker requires virtualization

Tags: docker

I’m using Docker for the first time. When I start Docker, I ask to enable virtualization.
The problem is that virtualization is enabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekAXQ.png)

Comment: Did you enable it in the BIOS of your PC, as well as Windows Features? It can be enabled on some machines in the Windows menu, but not configured in BIOS. Also, please list your Windows version and Docker version; it will help for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows Docker toolbox screen. It does not work with Hyper-V enabled.
You have to options:

1) Disable hyper -v (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4bb94f4e-3775-4f38-a4c8-cf2e872c103f/how-to-turn-off-hyperv-permanently) Docker Toolbox needs Vbox 64bit but it cannot work with Hyper-V enabled.

2) **suggested**: Install Docker Desktop for Windows. (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) it runs on hyper-v. It's also supported by Docker. The toolbox is a legacy way of running Docker and there's no more support for it.

On some computers, you need to enable virtualization in their BIOS. Reboot the PC, enter BIOS setting and search for the option to enable it. (https://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios)

Comment: hyper -v disabled